# Board and Card Games Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :D

**Note:** This eval will be closing on **27 September 2012**. Get your votes in!

Comment: I am curious as to what an up/down vote would mean with respect to our content. ie If a question is good, but the answers are poor or visa versa is that a downvote or upvote. Why are the questions never separated from the answers, or is that intentional?

Comment: @user1873 It's intentional. The best thing I do in that situation is say to myself, "If I were a stranger who had just landed on this page thanks to Google, would I be happy or unhappy with all of the information here?" The answer to that question usually is how I would vote.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, everyone! :)

Answer (score 12):

[Bottom card drawn during epidemic: What happens if there is already more than one disease cube in the city?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8115/bottom-card-drawn-during-epidemic-what-happens-if-there-is-already-more-than-on)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I am torn on this one. The answer is excellent, providing references that explain why the correct answer is supported by the rules. The question while clear,should have been directly answerable by reading the rules.

Comment: Setting aside being miffed that my simultaneous (yet admittedly lesser answer) has received 0 up votes. :)  I like this one.  I've had plenty of cases where even after several careful readings of the rules I've misunderstood or just plain missed something that becomes obvious when it's pointed out.  I like that we're here to help out everyone that has problems like this.

Comment: I definitely agree with @PatLudwig, I've often been in this situation!

Comment: @Pureferret - getting 0 upvotes or missing rules that are right in front of you? :)

Answer (score 10):

[How likely are you to lose because Fool's Landing sinks into the abyss?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/how-likely-are-you-to-lose-because-fools-landing-sinks-into-the-abyss)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: @tttppp, answer is probably the more correct answer, and breaks it down by number of players and difficulty. The only reason I have yet to accept it is because I have yet to check the math. (The diver section is much more complex, requiring a simulation). This is the kind of question I like, statistical.

Comment: I wouldn't want the site to devolve into a constant string of these difficult statistical questions, but they make for good spice :)

Comment: I'd prefer if the summary was at the start....besides that, good Q&A

Comment: @Pureferret Done!

Comment: @PatLudwig I wouldn't want to answer a constant string of these questions either ;-)

Answer (score 8):

[Does Goblin Arsonist's ability deal 2 damage when there are two in play?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8133/does-goblin-arsonists-ability-double-when-there-are-two-in-play)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I like how the answer took the time to explain and generalize things thus dispensing more knowledge concisely.

Answer (score 7):

[If I fail to defeat all defenders of a fortified site, does this count as a forced withdrawal?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8091/if-i-fail-to-defeat-all-defenders-of-a-fortified-site-does-this-count-as-a-forc)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is the kind of rules question I like to see. The rulebook isn't clear enough,.and it is necessary to consult an FAQ or the designers comments.

Comment: While our answer adds little more than the already existing BGG thread, I see value in presenting the answer, and clearly denoting it as from the designer.  You can get that from the BGG thread, but it takes a little work to realize that the answer is authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

[How long does it take to play Le Havre with different numbers of players?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8102/how-long-does-it-take-to-play-le-havre-with-different-numbers-of-players)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: par - maybe a bit negative.  This question could use several more answers from people with extensive experience with the game so that the questioner can judge whether there is a consensus that one answer with 2 votes cannot give.  I may have to input mine...

Comment: I'm not a big fan of how-long questions. Particularly for the type of games that tend to be topics on BCG, there can be a significant variance between a "standard" time and the time a given group can expect to play; I'm not sure if there's even a factor that a group could use to determine their expected play time given a standard, e.g. our groups has rules lawyers, so we add 25% to the listed time, or we're all novices, so we add 50%.

Answer (score 0):

[Could player discard nearest cards to place the part of `War Machine` in proper order?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8146/could-player-discard-nearest-cards-to-place-the-part-of-war-machine-in-proper)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Torn once again. Question could be answered by the rules.

Comment: par - we don't make the internet better or worse by having this question.  It is a common fallacy for folks to ask questions phrased like, "Can I do this? The rules don't prohibit it!"  We should do a better job of challenging folks to provide evidence of why they think they should be allowed to do the action in question.

Comment: I'm with Pat, but I don't think the question is bad.

Answer (score -2):

[Can you use Trader to gain a Silver instead of a Farmland, but still get the buy side-effects of Farmland?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/can-you-use-trader-to-gain-a-silver-instead-of-a-farmland-but-still-get-the-buy)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question is fine, but the accepted answer does not provide references to an official source. The 2nd answer provides references for part of the question, but does not address the Treasury/Smuggler questions. I believe the answers are correct, but without official sources to support the answers, it is just an opinion.

Comment: The question should have been cleaned up.  It asks 2 questions and includes an answer within it.  A poor moderating job by yours truly on this one.

Answer (score -3):

[How long does the copyright for a game last, after it is out of print?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8109/how-long-does-the-copyright-for-a-game-last-after-it-is-out-of-print)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Common misconceptions about abandonware exist for boardgames as well as videogames, this should clear those up.

Comment: par for me.  Legal advice on SE sites is as useful as legal advice on BB's IMHO.  The question should at least specify which country the asker is concerned about.

Answer (score -5):

[Trash an Estate or Curse your opponents? Full Version](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8093/trash-an-estate-or-curse-your-opponents-full-version)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Another good question, that lacks a good answer in my opinion. I think the lack of votes and answers reflect on the amount of expertise that would be necessary to confirm the correct answer.

Comment: Compare to the question that [spawned this one](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/to-trash-an-estate-or-to-curse-my-opponents).  The original dealt with a specific question that could be answered in a concise way. This question is asking for a nearly book length answer.

Answer (score -5):

[Good Euchre bidding strategy guide?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8103/good-euchre-bidding-strategy-guide)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Both current answers are incomplete. One provides a reference for bidding (although the quality of the link leaves much to be desired), the other provides no reference. The best answer would probably be to sum up the general strategy, but then provide references to more in depth strategy. It might be the case that this question is too broad anyway.

Comment: I've played a lot of Euchre.  Both answers are junk.